# How to use Jinja in Django framework?

Tags: django, jinja2

I want to access the elements of a list using Jinja.

Here in the below code both "id" and images are list.
image_name is the field that stores the image

```
   {% for blog in id%}    
        <h3>{{blog.news_title}}</h3><br/>     
        <a href="/blog/article/{{blog.slug}}"><img src="images[loop.index0].image_name"/></a><br/>
        <time>{{blog.news_date}}</time><br/>
        <a href="/blog/article/{{blog.slug}}">click here</a><br/>
    {% endfor%}</li>
```

Views.py

```
def BlogViews(request,blog_type):
    """
        The blogs are displayed according to the latest, current-month and last-month classification
    """
    blog_type=blog_type.replace('-','_')
    response_blog=requests.get("API" % (settings.BASE_URL,blog_type),headers=headers,verify=False)
    if(response_blog.status_code==200):
        data_blog=response_blog.json()
        if(data_blog['ErrorCode']==0 and data_blog['SubErrorCode']==0):
            blog=BlogYearViews()
            blog_images=BlogImages(request,data_blog)
            return render(request,"CombinedBlog.html",{"id":data_blog['Data'],"years":blog,"images":blog_images})
        else:
            return render(request,"Page404.html")
```

```
def BlogImages(request,data_blog):
    """
        Returns a list of all the images
    """
    data_image_list=[]
    for i in range(0,len(data_blog['Data'])):
        images=data_blog['Data'][i]['image_id']
        response_image=requests.get("API"%(settings.BASE_URL),headers=headers,verify=False)
        data_image=(response_image.json())
        data_image_list=data_image_list+data_image['Data']
    return (data_image_list)
```

Comment: You are *not using Jinja*. You are using Django template language.

Comment: Any Solution for using Django Template Engine for the above problem?

Comment: Not without seeing what BlogImages is.

Comment: I have added BlogImages to the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to zip the two lists together in your view and iterate through them in the template.

```
blog_images = BlogImages(request, data_blog)
blogs_and_images = zip(data_blog['Data'], blog_images)
return render(request, "CombinedBlog.html", {"blogs_and_images": blogs_and_images, "years":blog})
```

...

```
{% for blog, image in blogs_and_images %}    
    <h3>{{ blog.news_title }}</h3><br/>     
    <a href="/blog/article/{{ blog.slug }}"><img src="{{ image.image_name }}"/></a><br/>
    <time>{{ blog.news_date }}</time><br/>
    <a href="/blog/article/{{ blog.slug }}">click here</a><br/>
{% endfor %}</li>
```

Note, you really should be using the `{% url %}` tag to create the hrefs rather than building it manually like that. Also note, your BlogImages function doesn't need to take the request, since it never uses it, and is anyway extremely un-Pythonic. It should look like this:

```
def blog_images(data_blog):
    data_image_list = []
    for blog in data_blog['Data']:
        image_id = blog['image_id']
        response_image = requests.get("API" % settings.BASE_URL, headers=headers, verify=False)
        data_image = response_image.json()
        data_image_list.append(data_image['Data'])
    return
```

data_image_list

Answer (score 0):

To access `images` list using index you can use **forloop.counter**.

You can use either:

```
{{ forloop.counter }}  # index starts at 1
{{ forloop.counter0 }} # index starts at 0.
```

> **In template, you can do:**

```
<img src="{{images[forloop.counter0].image_name.url}}"/>
```

**Advice:**

- You should consider renaming **blog lists** as `blogs` or `blog_list` inplace of `id`.

Comment: I have already tried the solution but it no images are being displayed

Comment: Post your **models.py** and **views.py**.

Comment: Check my edited question for the changes you had asked for and there is no Models.py as the data is being received from an API

Comment: And when I tried your solution it gives the following error "Could not parse the remainder: '[ forloop.counter0 ].image_name.url' from 'images[ forloop.counter0 ].image_name.url'"